# Node js Socket Server error the handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format

Tags: c#, node.js, socket.io

I have node express socket.io server that is communicating with a socket.io javascript client via a website.
Now i want to send data to that socket from my C# backend code. For this

i am using this open source [H.Socket.IO](https://github.com/HavenDV/H.Socket.IO/)

```
 SocketIoClient client = new SocketIoClient();

            client.Connected += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine(@"Connected: {args.Namespace}");
            client.Disconnected += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine(@"Disconnected. Reason: {args.Reason}, Status: {args.Status:G}");
            client.EventReceived += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine(@"EventReceived: Namespace: {args.Namespace}, Value: {args.Value}, IsHandled: {args.IsHandled}");
            client.HandledEventReceived += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine(@"HandledEventReceived: Namespace: {args.Namespace}, Value: {args.Value}");
            client.UnhandledEventReceived += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine(@"UnhandledEventReceived: Namespace: {args.Namespace}, Value: {args.Value}");
            client.ErrorReceived += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine(@"ErrorReceived: Namespace: {args.Namespace}, Value: {args.Value}");
            client.ExceptionOccurred += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine(@"ExceptionOccurred: {args.Value}");

            //await client.ConnectAsync(new Uri("wss://socketio-chat-h9jt.herokuapp.com/"));
            await client.ConnectAsync(new Uri("wss://localhost:1465/"));
```

When i connect to demo server then it will connect but when i connect to my local node js server it will gives error

```
 The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are connecting to a locahost try to not use secure websockets. E.g. change `wss://localhost:1465/` to `ws://localhost:1465/`, so it uses `ws://` instead of `wss://`.